# Redirecting in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to understand if there is any difference between these two ways to do a redirection in symfony.

## 1 Via config without custom controller

As explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html).

```
# app/config/routing.yml

# ...

codes:
    path: /codes # redirect /codes to /code
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /code
        permanent: true
```

## 2 Via redirect() method in a custom controller

As explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting).

```
class RedirectsController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/codes")
     */
    public function codesAction() {
        return $this->redirect('/code', 301); // redirect /codes to /code
    }
}
```

When I talk about differences I mean things like performance, ease of use and maintainability.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you don't need to create a controller. You can manage everything from the configuration, and this is a convenience.
The redirect will be made by [RedirectController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/eee117285ae84b9aa859814d6d0cef9fd7f05baa/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php). In terms of performance  there is no difference between the two methods.

If what you have to do is redirect then go with the first method.

Comment: Thanks for the note about performance. 

In our case, we already have several redirections happening in a custom controller, so will keep adding them there, for the sake of keeping all them together.

But If I ever need to implement these from scratch, I'd probably follow the first method.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your first solution will redirect without using a specific controller, using only configuration, whereas your second solution will do your action and then redirect. These are two different use cases and they are not the same.